# Why is my array not working with innerhtml?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a website, and I've got some code that isn't working. How would I go about fixing it?

Here it is:

```
    <h1>Dmitry dances to</h1> <h1 id="danceto">Rock n' Roll</h1>
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="danceTo();" />

    <script>

    var element = document.getElementById("danceto")

    var songs= new Array("Vocaloids","Dubstep","Cries of the Damned");
        var random = songs[Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length)];

    function danceTo() {
    element.innerHTML = +songs+;
    }
    </script>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: *"How would I go about fixing it?"* First you have to find out what's wrong. In order to do that, [learn how to debug JavaScript code](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/). Specifically: Open your browser's developer tools and look at the error in the console. Stack Overflow is not a debugging service. We expect that you have done some debugging yourself (i.e. tried to solve the problem yourself).

Comment: So many problems with few lines of code... you should start with the basics and find a getting started tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have some errors and wrong logic, I think you want this:

```js
var element = document.getElementById("danceto")
var songs= new Array("Vocaloids","Dubstep","Cries of the Damned");

function danceTo() {
   var random = songs[Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length)];
   element.innerHTML = random;
}
```

```html
<h1>Dmitry dances to</h1> 
<h1 id="danceto">Rock n' Roll</h1>
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="danceTo();" />
```